# How to extract part of string and save it in new txt file (findstr or other tool)

Tags: windows, cmd, findstr

I have txt a file with 500 mln lines (over 100GB)

```
Data: xxxx
Lng: Java:version- xxxx
Code: xxx
Data: xxxx
Lng: Java:version- xxxx
Code: xxx
Data: xxxx
Lng: Java:version- xxxx
Code: xxx
Data: xxxx
Lng: Java:version- xxxx
Code: xxx
Data: xxxx
Lng: Java:version- xxxx
Code: xxx
Data: xxxx
Lng: Java:version- xxxx
Code: xxx
```

I want to extract part of first, fourth, seventh, tenth, thirteenth, sixteenth etc. etc. line
How to do this?
For now I used findstr (great, really fast tool) but it extract whole line with whole string, 
and i just need only part of string from this lines
here is my code

```
findstr Data data.txt > done.txt
```

but when i run this code i have

```
Data: xxxx
Data: xxxx
Data: xxxx
Data: xxxx
```

instead of:

```
xxxx
xxxx
xxxx
xxxx
```

How to extract just "xxxx" to new file to "save some space on my HDD":)?

Answer (score 1):

`findstr` has only a tiny subset of REGEX and *always* returns the whole line. You need to split it up with a `for /f` loop. You want the second token delimited by a space (it's one of the default delimiters, so you don't have to define it explicitly). To be exact, anything after the first token (`*`):

```
(for /f "tokens=1,*" %%a in ('findstr /b "Data:" data.txt') do echo %%b) > done.txt
```

Note: the whole output of the `for /f` loop is redirected in one go, which is a big time saver with big files. If you write each line individually, the file has to be opened, read until the end of the file, written and closed again for every single line. The bigger the file is, the greater is the saved time (it goes up to a factor of several hundred or even thousands with really big files)

Comment: Aha, `/B` obviates the need for regex here at all.  I wonder if `(for /f "tokens=1,*" %%a in (data.txt) do (if "%%a" EQU "Data:" (echo %%b))) > done.txt` has any shot of having better or comparable performance? On the one hand, I would think a compiled, purpose-specific executable like `findstr` would be much faster at text searching, but on the other if the `for` is required, anyways, to post-process `findstr`'s output maybe there's an advantage to having the `for` do everything and omitting `findstr` entirely. (Interpreting that `if` for 500 million lines will probably be a killer, though.)

Comment: It's the `for` loop that eats the time. I doubt trading `findstr` against `if` does change much, but you are the one with the big file to test. (I see, you already spotted my typo - corrected)

Comment: On second thought, several million `if`s are probably "a bit" slower than the single `findstr`.

Comment: I'm not the question author, but I suppose `findstr` would drastically reduce the number of lines the `for` ever sees.  If only every third line is a `Data:` line, then that'd be 500 million lines for `findstr` to process and 166 million lines for `for` to process, or all 500 million for `for`+`if` to process.  I think the former would definitely win.

Answer (score 0):

There is a `/R` switch that allows you to specify a regular expression to match, but I'm not sure in what version of Windows/`findstr` that was added.

To match lines that begin with `Data:` you could use something like this...

```
findstr /R "^Data:" data.txt
```

That breaks down as follows:

- `^` - Beginning of line (in case `Data:` might appear anywhere else in a line)
- `Data:` - The literal text `Data:`

That will return the entire line, including the `Data:` prefix.  To strip the prefix off, an expression like this...

```
(?<=^Data:).*
```

...could be used, but evidently `findstr` doesn't support the `(?<=)` positive lookbehind assertion.  PowerShell [does](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/standard/base-types/grouping-constructs-in-regular-expressions#zero-width-positive-lookbehind-assertions), which you could use by pasting and running the following at PowerShell prompt...

```bsh
Select-String -Pattern '(?<=^Data:\s+).*' -Path 'data.txt' `
    | ForEach-Object -Process { $_.Matches[0].Value } `
    | Set-Content -Path 'done.txt' -Encoding 'UTF8'
```

Once you've got PowerShell at your disposal, finding lines that begin with `Data:` isn't *that* complicated so as to require regular expressions, so you could potentially get better performance by [finding the lines](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_comparison_operators) and [extracting the text](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.string.substring) manually...

```bsh
Get-Content -Path 'data.txt' `
    | Where-Object { $_ -like 'Data:*' } `
    | ForEach-Object -Process {
        # Find the index of the first non-whitespace character after "Data:"
        # This avoids allocating another [String] with $_.TrimStart() or $_.Trim()
        for ($startIndex = 5; [Char]::IsWhiteSpace($_[$startIndex]); $startIndex++)
        {
            # Incrementing $startIndex is the job of this loop, so no body necessary
        }

        return $_.Substring($startIndex)
    } | Set-Content -Path 'done.txt' -Encoding 'UTF8'
```

Comment: sorry there was amistake, of course I mean `findstr Data data.txt > done.txt` (not Login)

Comment: i did try `findstr /R "^Data:\s+.*" data.txt > done.txt` and didn't work :( I also try  `findstr /R "^Data:\s*.*" data.txt > done.txt` and work but with whole line: `Data: xxxx` which is not what I am looking for

Comment: Since it's just lines that begin with `Data:` you want that simplifies the pattern a bit, but it looks like it's not possible to extract the text you want with `findstr` alone.  I added a couple PowerShell alternatives as well.

Comment: Thanks Mate! You are very kindly.